# How to login: "After following the steps in firecracker custom rootfs using alpine"

Tags: alpine-linux, rootfs, firecracker

I have followed the below steps for creating a custom rootfs image for booting with firecracker:-

https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker/blob/master/docs/rootfs-and-kernel-setup.md

Once the VM is up, it asks for the login username and password.

I have tried root/root just like the one provided in the hello-rootfs image provided in examples. But unable to login via the same credentials.

Do we need to add any other module / configuration apart from the steps mentioned in the doc for user login?

Answer (score 2):

You can use chroot to set root password inside the container:

```sh
chroot /my-rootfs
passwd
```